# Collapsed input bar is narrower when browser's width >= 768px

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

**CODE:** (with bootstrap3 and jQuery)

```
<body>

  <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: transparent; max-height: 50px;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10">

        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
            <li><a href="#" class="icon_navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse1" style="padding: 15px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down icon_navbar_color"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse1" style="">
            <form class="navbar-form">
              <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="max-width: 100%;">
                <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search icon_navbar_color"></i></button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

**jsfiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/o2daoew5/

This code performs opening `collapsed div` under the `navbar`.

When Browser's width is shorter than 768px, It's input bar wide enough.

But Browser's width is more than or equal 768px, It's input bar becomes shorter.

**Question:**

I want to make this input bar's width fully responsive to browser's width. Not becoming shorter. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class `form` not `navbar-form`

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse1" style="">
    <form class="form">
      <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="max-width: 100%;">
        <input class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search icon_navbar_color"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```